# $\sin x+\cos x=\frac{5}{4}$, find $\cos(4x)$ without a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It is given that $\sin x+\cos x=\frac{5}{4}$. I need to find the exact value of $\cos(4x)$. I do know how to find it with a calculator, but do not know how to without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you square both sides you get
$$
1+2\sin x\cos x=25/16
$$
or
$$
\sin(2x)=9/16
$$
Then
$$
\cos(4x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)=1-162/256=94/256.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi 4\right)$$
$$\cos 4x=-\cos\left(4\left(x+\frac\pi 4\right)\right).$$
Let $y=x+\pi/4$. If we know $\sin y$ we can work out $\cos 2y=1-2\sin^2y$
and then $\cos4y=2\cos^22y-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1+\sin2x=\frac{25}{16}$$
$$\sin2x=\frac{9}{16}$$
$$\cos4x=1-2(\sin2x)^2=\frac{94}{256}$$